# XmlElement annotation not found

Tags: java, maven, installation

Apparently, the XMLElement annotation class can't be found. The project builds and deploys successfully on another computer, which makes me think this is an installation issue. However, I can't find any way of fixing this.

I've already switched by installation to run on oracle JDK:

```
@:~/$ java --version
    java 11.0.4 2019-07-16 LTS
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS, mixed mode)
@:~/$ javac --version
    javac 11.0.4
```

The error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:436)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init> (JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:139)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init> (JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:126)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule.setupModule (JaxbAnnotationModule.java:90)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule (ObjectMapper.java:751)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModules (ObjectMapper.java:951)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.<clinit> (PipelineOptionsFactory.java:468)
    at com.spilgames.dataflow.portal.flows.PortalEvents.main (PortalEvents.java:73)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:830)
```

It seems that one of the dependencies (codehaus.mojo) is referencing to it, but it doesn't exist:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project dwh-dataflow-portal: An exception occured while executing the Java class. javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project dwh-dataflow-portal: An exception occured while executing the Java class. javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from java 11 jaxb annoations has been removed and jaxb dependency to your project

Comment: And that solved it. Thank you so much, I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566620/include-jaxb-using-maven to add jaxb dependencies and now it finally works.

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened after a sudden update of `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0` from another package I import.

I added this strictly annotation and it solved my runtime exception:

```
implementation (group: 'jakarta.xml.bind', name: 'jakarta.xml.bind-api') {
    version {
        // Fix NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
        strictly '2.3.3'
    }
}
```

I didn't add `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api` again because it was just updated to the newer jakarta version which replaces it.